# fade in multiple divs at once

Tags: jquery

I have managed to write some jquery that randomly fades in and fades out a set of divs one after the other but what I want to do is to fade in/out multiple divs at once.

Here is the current js i have:

```
(function makeDiv(){

var ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var imgid = ids[Math.floor(Math.random() * ids.length)];
var divsize = 120;


$newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
    'width':divsize+'px',
    'height':divsize+'px'
}).attr('id', 'img'+imgid+'');

var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();

$newdiv.css({
    'position':'absolute',
    'left':posx+'px',
    'top':posy+'px',
    'display':'none'
}).appendTo( 'body' ).fadeIn(500).delay(500).fadeOut(500, function(){
   $(this).remove();
   makeDiv(); 
}); 
})();
```

You can see it in action at www.vouchrs.com.

How can I achieve multiple fade ins/outs a once? thanks

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like that:

```
$(".something").click(function(){
   $(".divsToFadeInOrOut").each().fadeToggle();
});
```

I THINK this should do what you looking for.

Comment: No need to call `.each` as this is applied implicitly (plus your usage of the method is a bit off as well).

Comment: oh yeah, I actually just realised that myself.. Anyway, whats the point of .each(), then?

Comment: Each is used for iterating over a jQuery object, or for iterating over arrays and other generic object collections. Sometimes it's needed, most times it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling makeDiv upon the completion of the fadeIn, delay fadeOut chain at the moment. You could just do the "appendTo" in a loop without all that chaining and then use a selector to call that chain in parallel. I'd suggest adding a class to the new divs to make writing the selector easier.

Comment: Any chance of an example @jeff-watkins?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this also

(function makeDiv(){

```
var ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

var imgid1 = ids[Math.floor(Math.random() * ids.length)];
var divsize = 120;
var imgid = ids[Math.floor(Math.random() * ids.length)];
var idP = '';


$newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
    'width':divsize+'px',
    'height':divsize+'px'
}).attr('id', 'img'+imgid+'');

 $newdiv1 = $('<div/>').css({
    'width':divsize+'px',
    'height':divsize+'px'
}).attr('id', 'img'+imgid1+'');


var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();

 var posx1 = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
var posy1 = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();


$newdiv.css({
    'position':'absolute',
    'left':posx+'px',
    'top':posy+'px',
    'display':'none'
}).appendTo( 'body' ).fadeIn(500).delay(500).fadeOut(500, function(){
   $(this).remove();
   //makeDiv(); 
}); 

 $newdiv1.css({
    'position':'absolute',
    'left':posx1+'px',
    'top':posy1+'px',
    'display':'none'
}).appendTo( 'body' ).fadeIn(500).delay(500).fadeOut(500, function(){
   $(this).remove();
   makeDiv(); 
});
```

})();

You can write function to generate multiple divs like I have given an example of generating two divs simultaneously and I did this manually but you can create a function that generate multiple divs and at last you can call the makediv() function.